# Separete chat text depending of User Role

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I want to make chat discussion between `Admin` and `User` and based on User Role chat message and all data should be separate `left` or `right`

Here is my HTML render code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Chat</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right pull-left">Admin</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06/04/2021 08:35</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                Postovani
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right pull-left">User</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06/04/2021 08:36</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                treba mi pomoc ? 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right">Admin</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06/04/2021 09:06</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                sata
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name">User</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp">06/04/2021 10:50</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                asd
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right pull-left">Admin</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06/04/2021 11:05</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                haj
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right pull-left">User</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06/04/2021 11:26</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                kokoko
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  pull-right">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right pull-left">Admin</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">06/04/2021 12:53</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                adasdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my Index Page

```
 <div class="card card-primary direct-chat direct-chat-primary">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Chat</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                @if (ViewBag.discussion != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var discussion in ViewBag.discussion)
                    {
                        <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                            <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix  @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "" : "pull-right")">
                                <span class="direct-chat-name pull-right @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "pull-right" : "pull-left")">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
                                <span class="direct-chat-timestamp @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Admin" ? "pull-left" : "pull-right")">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                @discussion.Content
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

And style.css

```
<style>
   .direct-chat-text {
    border-radius: .3rem;
    background-color: #d2d6de;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    color: #444;
    margin: 5px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
}

.direct-chat-msg, .direct-chat-text {
    display: table;
}
</style>
```

Here is render css

```
element.style {
}
.card-primary:not(.card-outline)>.card-header, .card-primary:not(.card-outline)>.card-header a {
    color: #fff;
}
.card-primary:not(.card-outline)>.card-header {
    background-color: #007bff;
}
.card-header:first-child {
    border-radius: calc(.25rem - 0) calc(.25rem - 0) 0 0;
}
.card-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
}
.card-header {
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);
    border-bottom: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: "Source Sans Pro",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card-body::after, .card-footer::after, .card-header::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The problem here is that message is not separate left or right

[image]

Comment: And - what is the actual _question_ here?

Comment: Actual question is that I want to make chat app and separete chat message based on User Role, `left` or `right`

Comment: No, a mere “I want” is _not_ a question. Please go read [ask]. You need to explain to us, what the actual _problem_ is, what part of this you are having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to include exactly what is problem. I will update my question

Comment: @CBroe I update my question

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?  `pull-left` and `pull-right` have been replaced with `float-` classes in BS4, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/float/#classes

Comment: I am using version 4 of BT

Comment: Well then don’t expect `pull-left` and `pull-right` to have any effect, those existed in BS3 only.

Comment: Even If I change to `float-left` and  `float-right` the same problem

Comment: Probably because you put those classes all over the place. Why do you have them on the `.direct-chat-info` elements, and then also on both spans contained within that?

Comment: Because I need those content to be in one class, when I separete I get in new line