# How to separete Admin messages from User messages float-right and float-left

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I want to make a little chat application between `Admin` and `User` and I want to recognize which messages come from `Admin` and which one comes from `Manager`.
At this moment it is not important which message will go `left` or `right` Admin or Manager.
This is how it looks right now when I am logged in as `User`

[image: when I am logged in as User]

And this is when I logged in as `Admin`

[image: when I logged in as Admin]

And here is so far what I did

```
<div class="card-body">
                <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                    @if (ViewBag.discussion != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var discussion in ViewBag.discussion)
                        {
                            @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                            {
                                <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                                    <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
                                        <span class="direct-chat-name">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
                                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="direct-chat-text float-md-left">
                                        @discussion.Content
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                                    <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
                                        <span class="direct-chat-name">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
                                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="direct-chat-text float-md-right">
                                        @discussion.Content
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }

                            @*<div class="direct-chat-msg right @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "float-left" : "")">
                                    <div class="direct-chat-infos clearfix">
                                        <span class="direct-chat-name @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "float-right" : "float-left")">@discussion.ApplicationUser.Name</span>
                                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp @(discussion.ApplicationUser.Role == "Manager" ? "float-left" : "float-right")">@discussion.DateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="direct-chat-text">
                                        @discussion.Content
                                    </div>
                                </div>*@
                        }
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a demo out of it? Using Codesandbox or similar?

Comment: Sure, something like this 
https://codepen.io/sh-roen/pen/VwPmNdv?editors=1100

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967511/separete-chat-text-depending-of-user-role.